# Android dialog pause activity

Tags: android, concurrency, dialog, sequence, wait

I want to show dialog and it will pause activity . To wait user turn on the GPS . After that it can query database to fill the list .

The picture below description what I want to do

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is my code

```
public class RestaurantListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurants;
private SQLDataHelper dataHelper;

GPSTracker gpsTracker;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_list, null);

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

    if(!gpsTracker.canGetLocation)
    {
        showSettingsGPSAlert();
    }

    dataHelper = new SQLDataHelper(getActivity(), "restaurantDB");

    restaurants = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    dataHelper.openDB();
    Cursor cursor = dataHelper.query("Restaurant", new String[]{"Id", "ResName", "Logo", "Address", "Latitude", "Longitude"}, null
            , null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
            restaurant.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            restaurant.setResName(cursor.getString(1));
            restaurant.setLogo(cursor.getString(2));
            restaurant.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
            restaurants.add(restaurant);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    //Collections.sort(restaurants);
    RestaurantAdapter restaurantAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter(getActivity(), restaurants);
    setListAdapter(restaurantAdapter);
}

public void showSettingsGPSAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

My problems is it's not wait for user turn on GPS . It display list with dialog concurrency . I have searching many solution . But it not work . Please help !

Comment: Do you mean that you want to wait until user turns on gps? If you be more precise, I might be able to help you.

Comment: yes , it's excatly i want

Comment: Sorry to reply very late but, you should set setCancelable(false) to your dialog. Add a BroadcastReceiver that listens to if the GPS is turned on. (There should be one for that) And whenever your BroadcastReceiver receives that the GPS is turned on cancel your dialog and proceed. Or block any other operation until you receive true from LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 0):

Issue is beacause of you are checking GPS but the below only you placed code to update list. You can try this approache .Use Location Listener which has overrided methods `onProviderDisabled` and `onProviderEnabled` . After opening the Settings page if you check GPS settings then `onProviderEnabled` will called. So update your listview in that method

**Edit:**

```
LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
```

After the Call requestLocationUpdates:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    0,           // ms since last call
                    0,              //  m movement
                    locationListener);
```

Now define LcationListener:

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
            {  

            }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
                {

                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    Log.d("Hello7","onProviderEnabled");
                      //Update your listview here


                }  
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)                              {
                     Log.d("Hello10","onProviderEnabled");
                }
     }
```

you can stop locationUpdates also by  `lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);`

Comment: Yeah , Can you explain more details . Or add some code to your answer . Thanks you

Comment: But , if check like you said . It will not wait until user turn on GPS then query database to fill in listview . It can skip code below . I can check GPS by calling if(!gpsTracker.canGetGPS())
        {
            showSettingsGPSAlert();
        }